# rsync: if a module is not found, what can I check?

Tags: rsync

I am trying to simply copy a file from 192.168.1.225 to 192.168.1.228

I'm executing the following command from a ubuntu VM at ip 192.168.1.228. (I'm trying to do a ***pull***, if i'm not wrong in the term)

```
rsync rsync://realtebo@192.168.1.225/pihole_conf/black.list /etc/pihole/black.list
```

In the .225 I created the pihole_conf as follows

```
realtebo@192.168.1.225$ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
[pihole_conf]
comment = Pihole configuration
path = /etc/pihole
auth users = realtebo
hosts allow = *
hosts deny = * 
list = false
```

This is the error

```
@ERROR: Unknown module 'pihole_conf'
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1666) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

I'd like an help to understand the source of the problem.

Comment: I believe the syntax is `rsync://user@host::module/...`. Or just `user@host::module/...`.

Comment: According to the man page, `rsync://[user@]host/module/` is correct. But has the rsync daemon been restarted after modifying the configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are both allowing and denying all possible hosts from that module.

Remove the `hosts deny = *` line and it should work.

You do have a `secrets file` defined, I hope, which contains the allowed user and the corresponding password. It looks like you don't, but perhaps you redacted some of the rsyncd.conf contents without telling us.